# How to handle encoding in Python 2.7 and SQLAlchemy ‍☠️

Tags: python, mysql, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I have written a code in Python 3.5, where I was using Tweepy & SQLAlchemy & the following lines to load Tweets into a database and it worked well:

```
twitter = Twitter(str(tweet.user.name).encode('utf8'), str(tweet.text).encode('utf8'))
session.add(twitter)
session.commit()
```

Using the same code now in Python 2.7 raises an Error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2026' in
>   position 139: ordinal not in range(128)

Whats the solution? My MySQL Configuration is the following one:

Server side --> utf8mb4 encoding

Client side --> `create_engine('mysql+pymysql://abc:def@abc/def', encoding='utf8', convert_unicode=True)`):

**UPDATE**

It seems that there is **no solution**, at least not with Python 2.7 + SQLAlchemy. Here is what I found out so far and if I am wrong, please correct me.

Tweepy, at least in Python 2.7, returns unicode type objects.

In Python 2.7: `tweet = u'☠'` is a `<'unicode' type>`

In Python 3.5: `tweet = u'☠'` is a `<'str' class>`

This means Python 2.7 will give me an 'UnicodeEncodeError' if I do `str(tweet)`  because Python 2.7 then tries to encode this character '☠' into ASCII, which is not possible, because ASCII can only handle [this basic characters](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Conclusion:

Using just this statement `tweet.user.name` in the SQLAlchemy line gives me the following error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in
>   position 0-4: ordinal not in range(256)

Using either this statement `tweet.user.name.encode('utf-8')` or this one `str(tweet.user.name.encode('utf-8'))` in the SQLAlchemy line should actually work the right way, but it shows me unencoded characters on the database side:

`ð´ââ ï¸Jack Sparrow`

This is what I want it to show:

Printed: `‍☠️ Jack Sparrow`

Special characters unicode: `u'\U0001f3f4\u200d\u2620\ufe0f'`

Special characters UTF-8 encoding: `'\xf0\x9f\x8f\xb4\xe2\x80\x8d\xe2\x98\xa0\xef\xb8\x8f'`

Comment: Typo:  `☠` is codepoint `\u2620`.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use any encode/decode functions; they only compound the problems.

Do set the connection to be UTF-8.
Do set the column/table to utf8mb4 instead of utf8.
Do use `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the beginning of Python code.

More [*Python tips*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python)  Note that that has a link to "Python 2.7 issues; improvements in Python 3".

Comment: This: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` is just a comment and only a convention or does it bring any value to the code?

Comment: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` tells the interpreter wich encoding to use when parsing the file, it affects only files that contain non-ascii characters (literals). It does not effect the code in any other way. Also, have a look at the [mysql unicode section of the sqlalchemy doc](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#unicode), you need to add `?charset=...` to your connection url to change the connection charset